# Backpropagation with python/numpy - calculating derivative of weight and bias matrices in neural network

Tags: numpy, neural-network, backpropagation, derivative, calculus

I'm developing a neural network model in python, using various resources to put together all the parts.  Everything is working, but I have questions about some of the math.  The model has variable number of hidden layers, uses relu activation for all hidden layers except for the last one, which uses sigmoid.

The cost function is:

```
def calc_cost(AL, Y):
  m = Y.shape[1]
  cost = (-1/m) * np.sum((Y * np.log(AL)) - ((1 - Y) * np.log(1 - AL)))
  return cost
```

where AL is probability prediction after last sigmoid activation is applied.

In part of my implementation of backpropagation, I use the following

```
def linear_backward_step(dZ, A_prev, W, b):
  m = A_prev.shape[1]

  dW = (1/m) * np.dot(dZ, A_prev.T)
  db = (1/m) * np.sum(dZ, axis=1, keepdims=True)
  dA_prev = np.dot(W.T, dZ)

  return dA_prev, dW, db
```

where, given `dZ` (the derivative of the cost with respect to a linear step of forward propagation at any given layer), the derivative of the layer's weight matrix `W`, bias vector `b`, and deriv of previous layer's activation `dA_prev`, are each calculated.

The forward part that is complement to this step is this equation:  `Z = np.dot(W, A_prev) + b`

My question is:  in calculating `dW` and `db`, why is it necessary to multiply by `1/m`?  I've tried differentiating this using calculus rules but I'm unsure how this term fits in.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Your gradient calculation seems wrong. You do not multiply it by `1/m`. Also, your calculation of `m` seems wrong as well. It should be

```
# note it's not A_prev.shape[1]
m = A_prev.shape[0]
```

Also, the definition in your `calc_cost` function

```
# should not be Y.shape[1]
m = Y.shape[0]
```

You can refer the following example for more information.

[Neural Network Case Study](http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-case-study/)

Answer (score 0):

This actually depends on your loss function and if you update your weights after each sample or if you update batch-wise. Take a look at the following old-fashion general-purpose cost function:

[image]

Source: [MSE Cost Function for Training Neural Network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44038581/mse-cost-function-for-training-neural-network)

Here, let's say `y^_i` is your networks output and `y_i` is your target value.  `y^_i` is the output of your net.

If you differentiate this for `y^_i` you'll never get rid of the `1/n` or the sum, because the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivates. Since `1/n` is a factor to the sum, you won't also not be able to get rid of this, too. Now, think about what the standard gradient descent is actually doing. It updates your weights after calculating the average over all `n` samples. A stochastic gradient descent can be used to update after each sample, so you won't have to average it. Batch updates calculate the average over each batch. Which I guess in your case is `1/m`, where `m` is the batch size.